# docker-compose run app rake db:createで『Mysql2::Error』

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, docker-compose

お世話になっております。
下記の件、知見がある方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示お願いします。

## 起きている問題

`AWS`環境で`nginx`、`unicorn`、`mysql`を`docker`コンテナで構築し`docker-compose run app rake db:create`実行時に`Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")>`が起きました。

```
$ docker-compose run app rake db:create
Starting coffee_app_db_1 ... done
#<Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"coffee_app_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"karirin", "password"=>"karirin3948", "host"=>"localhost"}, {:charset=>"utf8"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
Created database 'coffee_app_development'
#<Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"coffee_app_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"karirin", "password"=>"karirin3948", "host"=>"localhost"}, {:charset=>"utf8"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
Created database 'coffee_app_test'
```

## 確認したこと

■mysqld.sock確認

```
$ touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld]$ ls
mysqld.sock
```

`mysqld.sock`がないというエラーだったので生成しましたが、解決しませんでした。
■mysqld起動確認

```
$ ps ax | grep mysqld
 5180 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
30674 ?        Ssl    1:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
30892 ?        Ssl    1:13 mysqld
```

mysqldは起動していることを確認しました。
■sudo mysql.server start

```
$ sudo mysql.server start
[sudo] ryouya のパスワード:
sudo: mysql.server: コマンドが見つかりません
```

`sudo mysql.server start`を実行したところ、コマンドが見つからないとでました。

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

`mysql --version`では正常にバージョンが表示されました。

## 関連ファイル

Dockerfile(Rails)

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
apt-get install -y apt-utils \
build-essential \
libpq-dev \
nodejs \
default-mysql-client
RUN mkdir /coffee_app
WORKDIR /coffee_app
ADD Gemfile /coffee_app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /coffee_app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install -j4
ADD . /coffee_app

EXPOSE 3000
```

Dockerfile(mysql)

```
FROM mysql:8.0.17

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y apt-utils \
locales && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
echo "ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
locale-gen ja_JP.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ja_JP.UTF-8
ADD ./docker/mysql/charset.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/charset.cnf
```

Dockerfile(nginx)

```
FROM nginx:1.12.2
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y apt-utils \
locales && \
echo "ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
locale-gen ja_JP.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ja_JP.UTF-8
ADD ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD ./docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails/Dockerfile
    command: bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c /app/config/unicorn.rb
  #  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /var/tmp
      - .:/coffee_app
    depends_on:
      - db
    extends:
      file: ./docker/mysql/password.yml
      service: password

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    extends:
      file: ./docker/mysql/password.yml
      service: password

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - coffee_app

volumes:
  db_data:
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: coffee_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: karirin
  password: karirin3948
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: coffee_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: karirin
  password: karirin3948
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: coffee_app_production
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOSTNAME'] %>
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

## 環境

ruby 2.5.1
rails 5.1.6
docker version 19.03.6
docker-compose version 1.24.0

Comment: railsのconfig/database.ymlの内容はどうなっていますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
質問本文の方に追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件解決しました。

原因は`test`、`development`環境だけ`AWS`上の`RDS`ではなく、
`EC2`上の`mysql`で実行しようとしていたためでした。
`database.yml`を`test`、`development`環境も`RDS`につながるように書き換えたら正常に動きました。

確認してくださった方々、ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m